# Get the known Laplace's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

Let $u(x,y), x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, a solution of

$$u_{xx}(x,y)+2u_{yy}(x,y)+e^{u(x,y)}=0, x^2+y^2\leq 1$$

Show that $\min_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} u(x,y)= \min_{x^2+y^2=1} u(x,y) $.

We suppose that $\min_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} u(x,y) \neq  \min_{x^2+y^2=1} u(x,y) $.

How can we find a function $U(X,Y)$ so that from $u_{xx}(x,y)+2u_{yy}(x,y)+e^{u(x,y)}=0$ we get the known Laplace's equation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a change of variables $y=\sqrt2\,z$, we get
$$
\underbrace{u_{xx}+u_{zz}}_{\text{Laplacian in $x,z$}}=-e^u\lt0
$$
which makes $-u$ [subharmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function) on
$$
x^2+2z^2\le1
$$
and thus $-u$ obeys the [Maximum Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle).

Comment: How can we deduce that we have to make the change of variables $y= \sqrt{2}Y$ ?  $$ $$

Also, is the following justification complete?

Since $\{ (x,y) | x^2+y^2 \leq 1\} \supseteq \{ (x,y)| x^2+y^2 =1 \}$ it has to hold that $\min_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} u(x,y)<\min_{x^2+y^2=1} u(x,y) \Rightarrow \min_{x^2+(2Y)^2 \leq 1} < \min_{x^2+(2Y)^2=1} U(x,Y)$

$U_{xx}(x,Y)+U_{YY}(x,Y)+e^{u(x,Y)}=0 \Rightarrow U_{xx}(x,Y)+U_{YY}(x,Y)=-e^{u(x,Y)}  \leq 0$

So from the minimum principle we have that $\min_{X^2+2Y^2 \leq 1} U=\min_{X^2+2Y^2=1} U $, that is a contradiction.

Comment: The cited Wikipedia article on The Maximum Principle says that "the maximum of a function in a domain is to be found on the boundary of that domain." Thus, the maximum of $-u$ on $x^2+2z^2\le1$ is to be found on $x^2+2z^2=1$, or equivalently, that the minimum of $u$ on $x^2+y^2\le1$ is to be found on $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Since $y=\sqrt2\,z$, the chain rule says that $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}u_y=u_z$ and $\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial z^2}u_y +\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\right)^2u_{yy} =u_{zz}$

Comment: Yes, I see... But I haven't understood how we can find which change of variables we can take... So is the above justification wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to find a contradiction? There is no need to argue by contradiction. If you wish to, you can manipulate the direct proof using the maximum principle into one using contradiction, but it is simpler not to.

Comment: In my notes, there is the following:

So we have $u_{xx}(x,y)+2u_{yy}(x,y)+e^{u(x,y)}=0 , x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow U_{xx}(x,Y)+U_{YY}(x,Y)+e^{u(x,Y)}=0, x^2+2Y^2 \leq 1$.

Since $\min_{X^2+2Y^2 \leq 1} U(x,Y) < \min_{X^2+Y^2=1} U(x,y)$, we deduce that $U$ has an interior global minimum and furthermore if $(x_1, Y_1)$ is such a point we have

$$\nabla{U(x_1, Y_1)}=0$$ 

$$\text{ Hessian } U(x_1, Y_1) \geq 0 \Rightarrow \Delta U(x_1, Y_1) \geq 0$$

However $e^{U(x_1, Y_1)}>0 \Rightarrow U_{xx} (x_1, Y_1)+U_{YY}(x_1, Y_1)+e^{U(x_1, Y_1)}>0$, contradiction.

$$$$

Comment: I was wondering if instead of that we could say $U_{xx}(x,Y)+U_{YY}(x,Y)+e^{u(x,Y)}=0 \Rightarrow U_{xx}(x,Y)+U_{YY}(x,Y)=-e^{u(x,Y)}  \leq 0$

So from the minimum principle we have that $\min_{X^2+2Y^2 \leq 1} U=\min_{X^2+2Y^2=1} U $, that is a contradiction.

Comment: The proposition you are trying to show is "Show that $\min\limits_{x^2+y^2 \le1}u(x,y) =\min\limits_{x^2+y^2=1}u(x,y)$". The argument you give above shows just that. No contradiction.

Comment: The proof in your notes is essentially proving the Maximum (or Minimum) Principle.